# Execute git pull on databricks notebook using CLI and/or API

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-rest-api, databricks-repos

Using Databricks Repos, you can add a git repo to Databricks and execute git actions such as `git pull`. This is done by clicking on the branch name in the top left, and clicking the button saying "Pull".

I would like to do this without clicking on things in my browser.

- What is the Databricks CLI syntax for triggering a git pull on a given repo?
- What is the Databricks API endpoint for triggering a git pull on a given repo?

I would assume that both are possible ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58836940/15629542) implies so), but providing just one would be sufficient to answer my question.

---

One might wonder what I expect to happen if a pull is non-trivial, eg. the branches have diverged or "your unstaged changes would be wiped out by pulling...". Simply erroring out would be sufficient in this case. I intend to ensure that it will never happen through other mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For databricks-cli it's the `databricks repos update` command:

```
>databricks repos update -h     
Usage: databricks repos update [OPTIONS]

  Checks out the repo to the given branch or tag. This call returns an error
  if the branch  or tag doesn't exist.

Options:
  --repo-id TEXT  Repo ID
  --path TEXT     Workspace path of the repo object
  --branch TEXT   Branch name
  --tag TEXT      Tag name
```

it will checkout branch even if repo is on the given branch:

```
databricks repos update --path /Repos/.... --branch releases
```

You can find the working demo of it in the [following repository](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo) that shows integration of Repos with Azure DevOps.

For REST API, there is the [corresponding endpoint](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/repos.html#operation/update-repo).  The only difference from CLI is that it accepts only Repository ID, not the path, but you can find Repos ID from path via [Get Status endpoint](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#get-status) of Workspace API.  You can find an [example in the history](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo/commit/5e77b95a65b479a1e4927019af7aafb931b4cd10#diff-7915b9b726a397ae7ba6af7b9703633d21c031ebf21682f3ee7e6a4ec52837a5R63) of the same demo repository (please note that Repos API could change since that time)

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent answer, Alex! I saw `repos update` as I was browsing through the docs, but somehow I thought it was updating something else besides the git state. Should have read more carefully I guess. I tried your commands and they worked, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Look into nutter demo - I run it since January